# How do I set up a lifecycle of less than 1 day in cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, lifecycle

I am currently looking to delete multiple objects in Cloud Storage.
I know that in GCS Lifecycle Configuration, I can set the value of age for lifecycles longer than 1 day.
However, I do not know how to delete them after 5 minutes.
If anyone has verified this, please let me know.

Currently, the AGE value is set to 0 and we are waiting for 24 hours to elapse.

Answer (score 1):

When trying 0age, 2 hours after placing the object, the lifetime cycle was triggered and the object was successfully deleted.

Therefore, I would like to close this thread.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?